# Getting project Resources folder path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to reference my project Resource folder as a path.
If I'm getting using

```
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString();
```

result as

```
"C:\\MYDEV\\MyProject\\bin\\Debug"
```

how can I get 
    "`C:\\MYDEV\\MyProject\\Resources`"?

Comment: Would embedded resources be what you are looking for? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/319292

Answer (score 4):

First you can get the folder of project use:

```
var projectPath =  Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
```

and then just combine it with your Resources folder

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Resources");
```

or

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"), "Resources");
```